# JQuery run every 5 minutes past the hour 5,10,15...55

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, settimeout

I'm looking to run a function every 5 minutes past the hour i.e. 08:05, 08:10, 08:15 etc..all day

how do I adapt:

```
 setTimeout(function(){ 
    xxxxxxx() 
 }, 300000);
```

to detect the current time -  if a multiple of 5 then run xxxxxx() function?

Comment: If you're using jquery (as tagged, though shouldn't be), then you're expecting the browser to be open all day?  Would you not prefer this to run server-side, akin to a schedule task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `setInterval` to call the function every second.
Then using a filter by current time having a minute divisible by 5 and seconds zero.

```js
var timer = 0;
timer = setInterval(function(){ 
 var currentdate = new Date();  
 if(currentdate.getMinutes() % 5 == 0 && currentdate.getSeconds() == 0) {
  console.log("Alarm");
 }
}, 1000);
//to stop: clearInterval(timer);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly straight forward:

- Wait until you reach 5 minute boundary using `setTimeout()`
- Use `setInterval()` to call the function every 5 minute

```js
function dosomething() {
  console.log("dosomething() called at " + new Date().toISOString());
}

var FIVEMINUTES = 5 * 60 * 1000;
var timeSincePrev = new Date() % FIVEMINUTES;
var timeUntilNext = timeSincePrev === 0 ? 0 : (FIVEMINUTES - timeSincePrev);

setTimeout(function() {
  dosomething(); // execute now
  setInterval(dosomething, FIVEMINUTES); // and after every 5 minutes
}, timeUntilNext);
```